# Laravel - Cannot Access Collection Indexes

Tags: php, laravel, collections

For sure it's an understanding issue on my part. I'm just trying to create a collection in which the elements can be output.

Example:

So I want to be able to execute:

```
$collection=collect([
    'index1' => 'data1',
    'index2' => 'data2',
    'index3' => 'data3',
]);

$row=$collection->first();
dd($row->index1);
```

Or similar.. But I get the error

> trying to get property of a non object.

It's an understanding issue about Laravel collections, I've read the Laravel documentation which goes from basic usage, to API reference. I cannot find the information on how to produce this basic static collection.

Can someone help?

Comment: `first()` does not work with associative array ..

Answer (score 1):

`$row=$collection->first();` points to the value `data1`, not an object/array.

To get the expected behavior try the code below, it wraps each in individual arrays.

```
$collection=collect([
                             ['index1' => 'data1'],
                             ['index2' => 'data2'],
                             ['index3' => 'data3'],
                            ]);

$row=$collection->first();
dd($row->index1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Laravel collections implement `ArrayAccess` you can simply access collection items as you do with an array

```
$value = $collection['index1'];
```

or you can use the `get` method on collections

```
$value = $collection->get('index1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I see the $collection['index1']; format works.

It's not exactly what I wanted, let me explain why. I know there's probably a better way of doing it although, for the sake of this particular coding requirement I'd like to know the answer to this.

I'm building a CRUD blade form.

On my blade I'll have 'field1' with initial output of $dbcollection->field1

Now of course if the database returns a null (create required) this output will fail. So what I'm trying to do here is pass blade a NULL-filled collection it understands so at least it doesn't complain about non instance of an object and avoiding @if statements on the blade form to account for differences in coding format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

`Controller`:

```
$collection=collect([
    'index1' => 'data1',
    'index2' => 'data2',
    'index3' => 'data3',
]);
$row = $collection->first();
```

`view`:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ ($row->index1 ? $row->index1 : '') }}" >
.
.
.
.
```